# Crazy redirect happening with no redirects set up

Tags: plugins, child-theme, wp-redirect, genesis-theme-framework

I have a website https://createandgo.com

If you hover over 'Design' in the top menu, then click 'How To Write A Blog Post' it adds like 21 URL extensions: https://createandgo.com/blog-writing-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/-tips/

The link SHOULD be: https://createandgo.com/blog-writing-tips/

Any ideas why this would be happening?

I have the Redirections plugin installed but I do not have any redirects set up with that domain.

I also have Pretty Links installed but I'm not seeing anything that would be causing this.

Before, a redirect was happening due to a media file having a similar extension and WP not knowing how to tell the difference between the two. But, I do not see any media files that would be causing this.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to rule these out, I would first disable Redirections and Pretty Links, then make sure my htaccess file was the same as the default WordPress htaccess file. I see it's a 301 redirect. Those get cached fairly hard, so make sure you clear your cache after these changes.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ or download a fresh copy of WordPress and get the htaccess file.